# CartoDB - How would I customize my legend to not be white and have blocks instead of bullets?

Tags: carto, legend, cartocss

First off, CartoDB is amazing.

I am trying to modify the look of my legend to look something like the one as seen on the "Elephant Movement in a Human Landscape" example on the CartoDB website. (http://spaceforgiants.org/?q=blog/2013/02/28/elephant-movement-in-a-human-landscape)

[image: Elephant Movement Customized Legend]

Similar to that example, my map has both point data and polygon data. I want to represent the point data with the standard bullets provided with the default category legend, but for the polygon layers I want to create colored (and also preferably semi-transparent) blocks.

Is there any way I can make these stylistic changes within the UI/legends/custom html window?

One last question, how would I go about changing the color of legend background?

My code looks like this:

EcoRegions

- Cascade Crest Montane Forest
- Cascade Subalpine/Alpine
- Pluvial Lake Basins
- Cold Wet Pumice Plateau Basins
- Deschutes River Valley
- Ponderosa Pine/Bitterbrush Woodland
- Pumice Plateau Forest
- John Day/Clarno Uplands
- High Lava Plains

I thought maybe I could replace the word "bullet" with something like "box" or "block" but it didn't work. I am not a programmer so don't laugh - I thought it was a good try.

Anyway, thanks for your help!

El_Tigre

Answer (score 1):

It's not posible to change the styles of the legend container from the CartoDB UI, although you can change the styles of the legend content. To build what you want I'd recommend you to create a [simple visualization using CartoDB.js](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-0)

Cheers!